# Windows batch file if else usage

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Sorry I am new to this stuff. I'd like to run in a certain sequence the same bat file with different parameters. I wrote a very simple batch file:

```
@echo off

REM Note: to see all command line usage options, run bsearch_headless.bat without any arguments.

call behaviorsearch_headless.bat -p test_behaviorsearch.bsearch -o pippo

ECHO
IF EXIST pippo.finalBests.csv (call behaviorsearch_headless.bat -p test_behaviorsearch.bsearch -o topolino)
else goto :eof  

:eof
ECHO Simulatione End!
PAUSE
```

It does not work because `else` is not recognized.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Obviously, if is not the problem you are asking about, but doesn’t the `ECHO` in the middle of your batch file need to be `ECHO.` or something?

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 21):

From the `if` documentation on the command line (via `help if` or [available in TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx) too).

> The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the
>   IF.  For example:
>
> ```
> IF EXIST filename. (
>     del filename.
> ) ELSE (
>     echo filename. missing.
> )
> ```
>
> The following would NOT work because the del command needs to be
>   terminated by a newline:
>
> ```
> IF EXIST filename. del filename. ELSE echo filename. missing
> ```
>
> Nor would the following work, since the ELSE command must be on the
>   same line as the end of the IF command:
>
> ```
> IF EXIST filename. del filename.
> ELSE echo filename. missing
> ```

So, your script would work if you replaced

```
IF EXIST pippo.finalBests.csv (call behaviorsearch_headless.bat -p test_behaviorsearch.bsearch -o topolino)
else goto :eof
```

With

```
IF EXIST pippo.finalBests.csv (call behaviorsearch_headless.bat -p test_behaviorsearch.bsearch -o topolino) else goto :eof
```

**OR**

```
IF EXIST pippo.finalBests.csv (
    call behaviorsearch_headless.bat -p test_behaviorsearch.bsearch -o topolino
) else (
    goto :eof
)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

ifelf.cmd:

```
@ECHO OFF
@IF EXIST "C:\boot.ini" (
@ECHO WoW! It may be M$Windows! 
) ELSE (
@ECHO Boot.ini Lost! My precious! Stolen! 
)
@ECHO .
@ECHO Wait 10 sec ...
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 > NUL
```

Comment: What's with all the `@`s?

Comment: @ProfPickle Hides map commands. Sample `@ECHO OFF` and `ECHO OFF`.

Comment: I know, but you don't need to use it once you put `echo off`.

Comment: @ProfPickle Yes, it is, but there have been times and programs ignore `ECHO OFF` but perceiving `@`. Think of it as a tribute to my paranoia or historical cases).

Comment: Fair enough, I understand paranoia.